# "The constructor is not visible" error

Tags: java, constructor, public

I have two classes :

First, with one constructor :

```
public class First {

    First (ObjectA myObjectA) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

And Second, with two constructors :

```
public class Second {

    Second (ObjectB myObjectB) {
        //do something...
    }

    Second (ObjectC myObjectC) {
        //do something else...
    }
}
```

When I want to instantiate my `First` class, Eclipse generates me an error ("The constructor is not visible"), I have to add `public` to the constructor of `First` :

```
First first = new First(myObject); //Error : "The constructor is not visble"
```

But when I instantiate my `Second` class, I have no error :

```
Second second = new Second(myObjectC); //No error...
```

Notes: I instantiate `First` in an other class, but I instantiate `Second` in `First`. `First` and `Second` are in the same package.

Can you explain me why ?

Comment: Surely "second" is in the same package as "first". Remember: Default access (i.e No modifier) is visible to classes in the same package. And, the Other class is in other package different from first.

Comment: In what packages are `First`, `Second` and the class(es) where you try to instantiate them?

Comment: "Access modifiers" in Java are a bit confusing and not especially "regular".  There's `public`, `private`, `protected`, and "no modifier".  `public` can be accessed from anywhere, `private` only from within the same class, `protected` from a subclass, and "no modifier" from any class in the same "package".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No access modifier for your constructor makes it **package private**.
Assuming that First and Second are in the same package, you can call Second's constructors from first.
Another class from another package, however, cannot access any of the constructors.

Comment: Subclasses too can't call a superclass constructor with no modifier

Answer (score 7):

Your class must be in 2 packages. If you don't mention any explicit access modifier Java will consider them as default access modifier. Then you **can only access them through the same package only**.

Access Modifiers (From least access to highest access)

1. **private** - Only within same class
2. **default** - Only within same package
3. **protected** - same package + children classes in other packages
4. **public** - From anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not mentined any modifier the access modifier is now **default**, that means **it is visible only within its own package**

If you try to use it out side the package, you'll face the current error.

Try to read :[What is the default access modifier in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164902/what-is-the-default-access-modifier-in-java)

If you did'nt get understood what @BackSlash is commenting, check the below link

Problem with : [Calling a method from a superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814209/calling-a-method-from-a-superclass)

Comment: Subclasses too can't call a  superclass constructor with no modifier

Answer (score 0):

just make your constructor **public**