# The constructor file(string) is not visible

Tags: java, string, eclipse, selenium, constructor

I get an error saying 'the constructor file[string] is not visible. Why am I getting this when I have declared both my method and class as public.

```
package appium1;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;

import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class desiredcap {

@Test
public void test() {
    File appDir = new File("src");
    File app = new File(appDir, "BookMyShow.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
   }
}
```

Comment: Please put all of the details of the question, in your question.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530382/the-constructor-is-not-visible-error).  Second answer:  "No access modifier for your constructor makes it package private."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You propably did import `File` class from the wrong package. What you want mostly is `java.io.File`

Comment: Thank you SilverNak. I removed File from gargaoyle and imported it from java.nio.file. It worked.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the normal Java `File` class, but rather something from Gargoyle Software.

Comment: Thanks a lot smith. That worked. I just realized that I had imported File from Gargoyle software instead of normally importing it from java.nio.file.*

Comment: No problem!  Please mark this answer as correct if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You probably imported wrong a class, try 
    java.io.File